# What is the default for the "required" property in RAML 1.0?

Tags: raml

I'm defining entities in RAML 1.0, and I feel that it's wasteful that the `required` attribute must be defined for each item if we want to make sure that it's (non-)optional. Is there a default value for this, and if so, which?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [RAML 1.0 specs](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md), the `required` attribute in RAML 1.0 entities [defaults to "true"](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#property-declarations), so it's only necessary to specify `required: false` for optional attributes.

Moreover, we can append a `?` to the attribute name (e.g: `age?`), to signify that it's optional (`required: false`), unless the `required` attribute is defined, in which case the question mark will be part of the actual attribute name.